# Tables with reference to R objects in sweave / latex

Tags: tables, r, knitr, sweave, rstudio

I'm using knitr/R-sweave to produce a pdf-document wit LaTeX-code. I want to make a table with some numbers produced by some R calculations in the R-code-chuck above this table. When I usually want to refer to an R object in the LaTeX/knitr-outout I use \Sexpr{}, but it doesn't seem to work within tables.

Here's what I got:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<Chunk1>>=
a= "1%"
b= "2%"
c= "3%"
d= "4%"
e= 1
f= 2
g= 3
h= 4
@

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Simple stratified data splits}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\textbf{Dataset} & \textbf{Observations}     & \textbf{Event rate}\\ \hline
Full data        & \Sexpr{e}                & \Sexpr{a}         \\
Training set     & \Sexpr{f}                & \Sexpr{b}         \\
Test set         & \Sexpr{g}                & \Sexpr{c}         \\
Evaluation set   & \Sexpr{h}                & \Sexpr{d}        
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

For some reason when I only add the first two rows:

```
\textbf{Dataset} & \textbf{Observations}     & \textbf{Event rate}\\ \hline
Full data        & \Sexpr{e}                & \Sexpr{a}         \\
```

...it works fine. I have tried adding the same row four times but that still produces the error: "Running pdflatex.exe on test.tex...failed"

I get the following from the log:

> LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier. Default added
>   (so using `tbp') on input line 71.
>
> LaTeX Font Info: External font cmex10' loaded for size (Font)
>
> <7> on input line 75. LaTeX Font Info:    External fontcmex10'
>   loaded for size (Font) <5> on input line 75. [1{C:/Users/Frederik
>   Hermann/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
>
> ] (test.aux) ) Here is how much of TeX's memory you used: 1244 strings
>   out of 493634 16308 string characters out of 3143709 72572 words of
>   memory out of 3000000 4665 multiletter control sequences out of
>   15000+200000 4116 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for
>   9000 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191 27i,8n,19p,284b,237s
>   stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s Output written
>   on test.pdf (1 page, 39879 bytes). PDF statistics: 18 PDF objects out
>   of 1000 (max. 8388607) 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
>   1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

I'm quite the rookie. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from using the "%" symbol in the RChunk.  When compiled by either knitr or sweave the "%" is passed through to LaTeX and then interpreted as the beginning of a comment, there by causing the rest of that line in the TeX file to be ignored.   Here is the revised code followed by the output.  (Note: I also turned off the echo of the R code in the output file.   This compiles fine with pdflatex on Windows 10.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<Chunk1,echo=FALSE>>=
a= "1 "
b= "2 "
c= "3 "
d= "4 "
e= 1
f= 2
g= 3
h= 4
@

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Simple stratified data splits}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\textbf{Dataset} & \textbf{Observations}     & \textbf{Event rate}\\ \hline
Full data        & \Sexpr{e}                & \Sexpr{a}         \\
Training set     & \Sexpr{f}                & \Sexpr{b}         \\
Test set         & \Sexpr{g}                & \Sexpr{c}         \\
Evaluation set   & \Sexpr{h}                & \Sexpr{d}        
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything that speaks against making a proper data.frame with `R` and use the [`xtable` library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf) to have a nice latex output? Here is an example. Of course you will have to change the `rownames()` according to what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

<<R library>>=
library(xtable)
@


\begin{document}

<<R dataframe , results = "asis" >>=
df <- data.frame ("Observations" = c(a = "1%", b = "2%", c = "3%", d = "4%"),
                  "Event rate" = c(1:4)
)

xtable(df)
@


\end{document}
```

Comment: I did not know about `xtable`. Thank you. However,  when I post the code you posted to a fresh .rnw-file, I get "Running pdflatex.exe on test2.tex...failed" again.

LOG:   `Overfull \hbox (59.24648pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 65--65
[][]\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 df[] []<-[] []data.frame[] []([][]"Observations"[] []=[] [
]c[][]([][]a[] []=[] []"1%"[][],[] []b[] []=[] []"2%"[][],[] []c[] []=[] []"3%"
[][],[] []d[] []=[] []"4%"[][]),[][] 
 []`


Any tips?

Comment: @FrederikVittingHermann A Problem with Latex ...Can you give some infos about your OS (Windows I guess...). Are you up-to-date with LaTex?  Did you check the Config in RStudio (Tools/Global Options/Sweave) Try with **knitr** and **XeLatex**. And very important : check the encoding of your file *UTF-8*. If nothing helps, could  you post `test2.tex`?